# md-datepicker is ignoring the custom margin

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-material

I am using AngularJS Material datepicker in my project and I am using some custom CSS for it which `md-datepicker` unfortunately ignores.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/avreddy/pen/opXrbd)

Here's a snippet:

```js
angular.module('myApp',['ngMaterial'])
```

```css
body{background-color:white}
.datePicker{
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" >
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

  <label>User Date</label><br>
<md-datepicker ng-model='userDate' class="datePicker md-primary"></md-datepicker>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Can you check and let me know if the solution works?

Comment: Yeah it worked thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's taking up, but the `display` is not right. Set the right `display` for the `<md-datepicker>`:

```
.datePicker {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ppJXeb**